# Steam not working on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, games, steam

I have installed steam on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit by using the deb file downloaded on the Steam site. First steam worked, but then ate the second use did not work anymore. So I completely un-installed and installed it again two times, by using `sudo apt-get install steam -y` and again with the .deb file of the website. The result is always the same: the installation goes well but when I launch Steam it does not work (do nothing). In particular when I launch it from the terminal the message is:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/home/manno/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: row 431: realpath: command not found
```

Can you please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Support for anything graphical or wine is going to be very limited on 14.04. I highly suggest you fresh install or upgrade to a more recent release, especially with steam and wine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have realpath installed.`sudo apt-get install realpath` did the job for me.